# Rust tokio_serial: async fn readable does not block execution. Runs with 100% CPU load

Tags: rust, serial-port, rust-tokio

I'm trying to implement something that shall handle a UART communication on a Linux PC with Rust. This is my first time writing anything in Rust, so I might be completely off.

Becasue the communication my protocol is somewhat asynchronous, I want to use `tokio`. I found the `tokio_serial` crate which seems to wrap a serial port into an async-usable API.

I tried the following code. It should receive data on the uart port and print it to the console and echo the bytes back. This works fine.

However, my program consumes 100% CPU load after the first byte is received. It works fine and does not consume CPU as long as no data has been received yet.  I added the commented out println! statement and saw, that `port.readable().await;` actually does not block but completes without any actual readable data.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
use std::{env, io::Write, process, str};
use tokio_serial::{self, SerialPortBuilderExt};

#[tokio::main(flavor = "current_thread")]
async fn main() {
    let baud_rate : u32 = 115200;
    let serial_port = env::args().nth(1).unwrap_or_else(|| {String::from("/dev/ttyUSB0")});
    println!("Open port {serial_port}");

    let mut port = tokio_serial::new(serial_port, baud_rate).open_native_async().unwrap_or_else(
        |e| {
            println!("Error: {:?}", e);
            process::exit(-1);
        }
    );
    

    let mut buf : [u8; 255] = [0;255];
    loop {
        let readable_res = port.readable().await;
        if let Ok(()) = readable_res {
            match port.try_read(&mut buf) {
                Ok(size) => {
                    println!("Got {} bytes: {}", size, str::from_utf8(&buf[0..size]).unwrap());
                    port.write(&buf[0..size]).unwrap_or_else(|e| {println!("{:?}", e); 0});
                },
                Err(e) => {
                    //println!("{:?}", e);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs for `readable`](https://docs.rs/tokio-serial/latest/tokio_serial/struct.SerialStream.html#method.readable) pretty clearly say: *"The function may complete without the socket being readable. This is a false-positive..."*  In other words, a `readable` future is guaranteed to complete when the socket can be read, but it is *not* guaranteed to *not* complete if it *can't* be read.

If you're reading in a loop you should probably be using [`read`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncReadExt.html#method.read) (via `AsyncReadExt`) instead of `readable` + `try_read`. This is far simpler and is easier to get right.

There isn't really a reason to do non-blocking I/O in an async context anyway. In sync code you typically use non-blocking I/O so you can do other things while you wait for I/O to be ready, but in an async context you can already do other things while you wait via the async runtime (tasks, `join!`, `select!`, etc.).

Comment: Thansk for the answer. I read the docs. However, I assumed the "may complete" means you MAY get some fals e positives and not a complete 100% CPU usage becasue it always completes.
I simply wasn't aware of the fact that adding AsncReadExt adds a async read method. I simply looked through the code and grabbed the first thing that was async because I couldn't really figure out how to use it. TBH, I still don't know how to make the way from saying: I have tokio_serial -> it implements an AsyncRead -> AsyncReadExt adds the async read method for everythign Async Read. This was not clear to me.

Comment: @GNA That's understandable. The way async stuff is structured can be difficult to understand at first. Basically, if you have some trait that gives you a `poll_*` method (`AsyncRead` here), there is probably an extension trait somewhere that provides access to that facility as a future.